# Splitting a string with range() in python

Tags: python, string, range

Is it possible to split a string like `x = '12.32,13.4,2.34,1.2'` into 12.32  13.4  and 2.34 etc  by using range(). I know range() can split `y = '12345'` into integers 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 just don't know if the range can differentiate "," delimiter and split them to output as float.

Comment: why don't you try this `'12.32,13.4,2.34,1.2'.split(',')`?

Comment: How do you split `12345` to integers using `range()`?

Comment: Assign `range = str.split` then with `range(x, ',')` it is possible.

Comment: to Avinash Raj, thank you this is most easy way.

Comment: @Vyktor , thank you I have mixed it with for in loop. For c in '1234' print c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just dont know if the range can differentiate "," delimiter and split them to output as float.

I assume you want this:

```
>>> map(float,'12.32,13.4,2.34,1.2'.split(','))
[12.32, 13.4, 2.34, 1.2]
```

You wont get any use out of `range` for this task.